# watchOS2 Paired Property

Tags: ios, watchos-2

Does anyone know of any reason why the Watch Connectivity property `paired` wouldn't be working properly?

I thought perhaps this was an early watchOS2 issue but we are at GM now and it still doesn't work.

I have a companion app installed on the watch but this property is always false for me. I have also tried `reachable` which also always returns false.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    if WCSession.defaultSession().paired {
        print("Watch connected")
    } else {
        print("No watch")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure to perform the [WCSession set up](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WCSession) before reading any of its properties:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()
    if session.paired {
        print("Watch paired")
    } else {
        print("No watch")
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Missed that in the docs. Thanks for your help. Seems strange that you have to do this because you effectively have to start a session each time even though a watch may not be connected.